# What are the advantages of using JSP? (java sever pages)

Tags: java, php, ruby-on-rails, jsp

What are the advantages of using jsp over PHP or Ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're a Java shop and you have a lot invested in that kind of infrastructure.

I wouldn't advocate using stock JSP for anything, though. There are toolkits that build on top of it that make life significantly easier for developers. The Tapestry/Hibernate combination is only one example.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly subjective and depends heavily on what kind of sites you are building. If you are just using plain JSP it offers little advantage. However, if you want to use one of the many Java frameworks (Spring, Hibernate etc.) it can offer many advantages, depending on the application.